# Is there a way to bind variables? PHP 5

Tags: php

Using [PHP 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Release_history) I would like to know if it is possible for a variable to dynamically reference the value 
of multiple variables?

For example

```
    <?php
    $var = "hello";
    $var2 = " earth";
    $var3 = $var.$var2 ;
    echo $var3; // hello earth
```

Now if I change either `$var` or `$var2` I would like `$var3` to be updated too.

```
    $var2 =" world";  
    echo $var3;
```

This still prints hello earth, but I would like to print "hello world" now :(

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Can this be done in any language? I've only seen it in flex but only binding data to UI.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to do this in PHP with simple variables. If you wanted to do something like this in PHP, what you'd probably do would be to create a class with member variables for var1 and var2, and then have a method that would give you a calculated value for var3.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick. I tested it on PHP 5.3 and it worked. Should also work on any 5.2.x version.

You could easily extend this with an "add"-Method to allow an arbitrary number of strings to be placed in the object.

```
<?php
class MagicString {
    private $references = array();
    public function __construct(&$var1, &$var2)
    {
        $this->references[] = &$var1;
        $this->references[] = &$var2;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        $str = '';
        foreach ($this->references as $ref) {
            $str .= $ref;
        }
        return $str;
    }
}
$var1 = 'Hello ';
$var2 = 'Earth';

$magic = new MagicString($var1, $var2);
echo "$magic\n"; //puts out 'Hello Earth'
$var2 = 'World';
echo "$magic\n"; //puts out 'Hello World'
```

Comment: both evil and neat at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

No. Cannot be done without utilizing some sort of custom String class.
Check the PHP manual for [types](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php) and [variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php), especially this passage:

> By default, variables are always
>   assigned by value. That is to say,
>   when you assign an expression to a
>   variable, the entire value of the
>   original expression is copied into the
>   destination variable. This means, for
>   instance, that after assigning one
>   variable's value to another, changing
>   one of those variables will have no
>   effect on the other. For more
>   information on this kind of
>   assignment, see the chapter on
>   [Expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php).

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit late, but it's interesting question.
You could do it this way:

```
$var = "hello";
$var2 = " earth";
$var3 = &$var;
$var4 = &$var2;
echo $var3.$var4; // hello earth
```

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the following code is a little closer to the required:

```
$a = 'a';
$b = 'b';
$c = function() use (&$a, &$b) { return $a.$b; };
echo $c(); // ab
$b = 'c';
echo $c(); // ac
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a function.

```
function foobar($1, $2){
$3 = "$1 $2";
return $3;
}

echo foobar("hello", "earth");
echo foobar("goodbye", "jupiter");
```